# In mvn test, Spring-test throws sql script errors in mvn test

Tags: spring, maven, junit, spring-batch, spring-test

I have three test cases.   They each execute successfully when run individually through RunAs > JUnit and mvn individual test case runs.   But when I run mvn test on all three together, the first two test cases execute properly, and the 3rd test case fails with SQL Script errors (table  already exists...).

My Test case fragment:

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = 

DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@TestExecutionListeners(DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/blueReport-ItemProcessor-test-context.xml" })
public class BlueReportItemProcessorUnitTest {


@Qualifier("jdbcTemplate")
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Qualifier("jdbcTemplateBMS")
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateBMS;

@Autowired
private CountryExclusionDAO countryExclusionDAO;

@Autowired
private BMSReportDAO bmsReportDAO;

@Autowired
private MappingFileDao mappingFileDAO;

// getting cached list of countries that needs to be skipped
private SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = SimpleCacheManager.getInstance();


// This is what we're going to test here
@Autowired
private BlueReportItemProcessor blueReportItemProcessor;

// Static test variables
private static String test_AccountId = "ACCT1";
private static String test_ProjectId = "PROJ1";
private static String test_ContractNbr = "CTR057";
private static String test_ChannelName = "CHANNEL5";
private static String test_ChannelNameBR = "For Our BR clients";
private static String test_ChannelNameIN = "This channel is for IN";
private static String test_Country = "821";  // Excluded country
private static String test_CountryName = "Russia";


@Before
public void setUp() {

    // Setup Account map data first
    jdbcTemplate.update("DELETE from ACCOUNT_MAP");
    jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO ACCOUNT_MAP(EXTERNALKEY, PROJECTID, EXTERNALSOURCE, CONTROLGROUP) VALUES('ACCT1', 'PROJ1', 'TESTCASE','GRP1')");

    // Setup BMS Shadow data next
    jdbcTemplate.update("DELETE from SHADOW_BMS");
    jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO SHADOW_BMS(PROJ_TYP_CD, SYS_CD, STAT_CK_CD, EXTRNL_KEY_CD, EXTRNL_SYS_CD, CNTRCT_NUM, PROJ_NUM, CNTRCT_LINE_ITM, CUST_NUM, CUST_CNTL_NUM, CUST_NM, CHRG_CD, PRDCT_ID, BILNG_CRNCY_CD, BILNG_ISO_CRNCY_CD, BILNG_CRNCY_DCM_NUM, CFTS_CRNCY_EXCH_RT, CFTS_CRNCY_EXCH_RT_EXPIR_DT, CHRG_CRNCY_CD, CHRG_ISO_CRNCY_CD, CTRY_CD, CMPNY_CD, OFFERING_CD, CNTL_GRP_CD) VALUES('NEW', 'GO', 'ONE', 'ACCT1', 'TESTCASE', 'CTR057', 'PROJNUM1', 14, 'C293', '004', 'Fozzies Rubber Chicken Factory', '923D', '9207-908', null, null, 0, 0, null, null, null, 'USA', 'IBM', 'GOLD-BAR', 'ESKIMO') ");

    //invoke CountryExclusionDAO to put all the countries in the exclusion list
    Map<String,String> countryExclusionsMap = countryExclusionDAO.getAllCountryExclusions();
    cacheManager.put("countryExclusionsMap", countryExclusionsMap);

    //for getting cached list of rows from BMSIW
    cacheManager.put("bmsReportDAO", bmsReportDAO);

    //for getting account mappings
    cacheManager.put("mappingFileDAO", mappingFileDAO);

}

/**
 * Test the Country Exclusion Logic
 */
@Test
public void testCountryExclusion821() {

    // This setup tests the originating country skipping logic
    BlueReport testBlueReport = new BlueReport();
    testBlueReport.setAccount_id(test_AccountId);
    testBlueReport.setProject_id(test_ProjectId);
    testBlueReport.setContractNbr(test_ContractNbr);
    testBlueReport.setChannel_name(test_ChannelName);
    testBlueReport.setIbm_country_num(test_Country);
    testBlueReport.setIbm_country_name(test_CountryName);

    BlueReport brOut = null;

    // Invoke the Processor
    try {
        brOut =  blueReportItemProcessor.process(testBlueReport);
        assertTrue("Expected status=Skipped", brOut.getStatus().contains(Status.SKIPPED.toString()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Assert.fail("blueReportItemProcessor caught an unexpected exception in: " + e.getCause());
    }

}
```

Here is the partial mvn test -X output:

```
[DEBUG] Adding to surefire test classpath: C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\surefire\surefire-junit4\2.12.4\surefire-junit4-2.12.4.jar Scope
[DEBUG] Adding to surefire test classpath: C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\surefire\surefire-api\2.12.4\surefire-api-2.12.4.jar Scope: test
[DEBUG] test classpath classpath:
[DEBUG]   C:\bluecost\target\test-classes
[DEBUG]   C:\bluecost\target\classes
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\4.3.12.RELEASE\spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\4.3.12.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\4.3.12.RELEASE\spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\4.3.12.RELEASE\spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-test\4.3.12.RELEASE\spring-test-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\batch\spring-batch-test\2.2.0.RELEASE\spring-batch-test-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\1.4\commons-io-1.4.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2\commons-collections-3.2.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\batch\spring-batch-core\3.0.8.RELEASE\spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.m2\repository\com\ibm\jbatch\com.ibm.jbatch-tck-spi\1.0\com.ibm.jbatch-tck-spi-1.0.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.m2\repository\javax\batch\javax.batch-api\1.0\javax.batch-api-1.0.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.m2\repository\com\thoughtworks\xstream\xstream\1.4.7\xstream-1.4.7.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.m2\repository\xmlpull\xmlpull\1.1.3.1\xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.m2\repository\xpp3\xpp3_min\1.1.4c\xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jettison\jettison\1.2\jettison-1.2.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\4.0.5.RELEASE\spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\4.0.5.RELEASE\spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\4.0.5.RELEASE\spring-expression-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\batch\spring-batch-infrastructure\3.0.8.RELEASE\spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.m2\repository\org\springframework\retry\spring-retry\1.1.0.RELEASE\spring-retry-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\5.1.44\mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.m2\repository\com\ibm\db2\jcc\db2jcc_license_cisuz\10.1.0\db2jcc_license_cisuz-10.1.0.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.m2\repository\com\ibm\db2\jcc\db2jcc\10.1.0\db2jcc-10.1.0.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.12\junit-4.12.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.m2\repository\commons-dbcp\commons-dbcp\1.4\commons-dbcp-1.4.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.m2\repository\org\hsqldb\hsqldb\2.4.0\hsqldb-2.4.0.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.m2\repository\commons-pool\commons-pool\1.6\commons-pool-1.6.jar
[DEBUG] provider classpath classpath:
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\surefire\surefire-junit4\2.12.4\surefire-junit4-2.12.4.jar
[DEBUG]   C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\surefire\surefire-api\2.12.4\surefire-api-2.12.4.jar

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Forking command line: cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\bin\java" -jar C:\bluecost\target\surefire\surefirebooter3090752069136285871.jar C
Running com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.AppTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.028 sec
Running com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.SimpleJobStepFunctionalTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.037 sec
Running com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.unit.BlueReportItemProcessorUnitTest
[ERROR] TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionL
tion: Failed to load ApplicationContext>java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitiali
to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [db/custom-db-assets.sql]: create table ACCOUNT_MAP( EXTERNALKEY VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, PROJECTID VAR
ion: object name already exists: ACCOUNT_MAP in statement [create table ACCOUNT_MAP( EXTERNALKEY VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, PROJECTID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, EXTERNA
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [db/custo
ULL, CONTROLGROUP VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL ); nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: object name already exists: ACCOUNT_MAP in statement [create t
10) NOT NULL )]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:491)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:238)
```

Comment: please add your test class and configuration so another dev can easily figure out the issue

Comment: @JamesD `Failed to execute SQL script` probably you have some data.sql or some other sql source. And  you should remove previous table before creating new one. It can be just a matter of setup or you can adjust your sql to remove table before creation/skip table creation

Comment: Yes - my scripts first remove the tables and triggers before recreating them - that's what happens in database initialization.   It works perfectly when run individually.  This only doesn't work in mvn when testing all of them one by one.

Comment: I believe this problem has been documented in spring-projects/spring-boot issue 1712, and fixed https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/4f67a2021435da0d84755865c06049194bec3bf3 and https://github.com/axibase/spring-boot/commit/1eebd0b70341df891b440aca5b507dc404d996c7  I'm using the latest Spring 4.3 release and the problem persists there.... :(  What can I do?

Comment: Are you by any chance running the tests in parallel with Maven?

Comment: You need to delete the `@TestExecutionListeners` declaration since you are effectively disabling the rest of the default listeners.

Comment: Why do you have two different `JdbcTemplate` instances injected? Are you using two different data sources / databases?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure how your database is built, I assume it's dbUnit or similar.

You need something like the following at the top of your tests, to make sure the Spring context is torn down after each test.

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@TestExecutionListeners(DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class)
```

Possibly other TestExecutionListeners, see [here](https://github.com/pkainulainen/spring-social-examples/blob/master/sign-in/spring-mvc-normal/src/integration-test/java/net/petrikainulainen/spring/social/signinmvc/common/controller/ITHomeControllerTest.java) for a full example

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - not sure exactly what it does, but I've seen it in the past examples.  
My runtime db is DB2 10.5 but the test cases are using HSQLDB in-memory database.   The data source has db initialization section defined that tears down and rebuild all db assets in correct order.  It seems that the create.sql script was run without the delete.sql script....

Comment: After adding those two statements to the top of my Test case, I'm now getting NullPointerExceptions in setUp() method - when trying to reference jdbcUtils object that should have been Autowired.  I'm adding portion of my Test Case source and the context files.

Comment: The example I shared uses an in memory database with dbUnit, you can copy that.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an omission on my part. I failed to include the drop script ahead of create script:

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" ignore-failures="DROPS">
*** <jdbc:script location="${batch.business.schema.drop.script}"/>
    <jdbc:script location="${batch.business.schema.script}"/>
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```